# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$ given that $|a_n|\leq |a_1|*q^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers.
There exists $0<q<1$ such that for every $n>1$, $|a_{n+1}|\leq q*|a_n|$ and also $|a_n|\leq |a_1|*q^{n-1}$.
Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Is there a short way to do it rather than writing a proof by definition?

Comment: What do you mean by shorter? The direct proof is pretty short.

Comment: You can use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 Do I need to prove that the series is monotonic, then bounded and then prove that the limit exists?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Can you please elaborate? I can easily find the limit of the right hand side of the inequation but not the left hand size

Comment: You can directly use the sandwich theorem if you know how it works and that $q^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $0 < q < 1$.

Comment: @Lilo $0 \leq |a_n| \leq |a_1|\cdot q^{n-1}$. If you have already proven that $q^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ whenever $0 < q < 1$ then it is a direct application. If you don't know that limit then the definition is the way to go.

Comment: I missed the part where I could just claim that $0\leq |a_n|$ on the left hand size.
Thanks, now it's obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** $\forall n \in \Bbb N, 0 \leq |a_{n+1}| \leq |a_n| \cdot q \leq |a_1| \cdot q^n$

Now, use sandwich theorem.